# codeigniter pagination error in id passing

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

```
 $category_id=$_GET['category_id'];
  $data['adsd']=$this->mymodel->select_ads_by_category($category_id);   
  $config["base_url"]=site_url('main/category_ads_display?category_id='.$category_id.'');

  $config["total_rows"]=count($data['adsd']);
  $limit=$config["per_page"]=1;
  $config["uri_segment"]=3;
        $config["use_page_numbers"]=TRUE;
  $this->pagination->initialize($config);
  if($this->uri->segment(3))
   $page=($this->uri->segment(3)-1)*$limit;
  else
  $page=0;
```

Hello friends i have pasted my code above,,everything is working fine,but when i click on  links of pagination the url is like this =localhost/blabla/main/category_ads_display?category_id=5/2(not working)

but i need the url to be as = localhost/blabla/main/category_ads_display/2?category_id=5(working)
please help me on this

Comment: Try to echo `$this->uri->segment(3)` I think it does not producing the number.also echo `$config["base_url"]` and let me know what it produce.

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro,but its all working fine,the thing is "/2" is coming at the end of url,but i need it in the middle before "?category_id", as i shown in the above

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 $category_id=$this->uri->segment(3);
 $data['adsd']=$this->mymodel->select_ads_by_category($category_id);
 config["base_url"]=site_url('main/category_ads_display/'.$category_id);

 $config["total_rows"]=count($data['adsd']);
 $limit=$config["per_page"]=1;
 $config["uri_segment"]=4;
 $config["use_page_numbers"]=TRUE;
 $this->pagination->initialize($config);
 if($this->uri->segment(4))
  $page=($this->uri->segment(3)-1)*$limit;
 else
 $page=0;
```

Now your new link will be like this `localhost/blabla/main/category_ads_display/5/2` for page 2 and 5 will be your category id

Comment: Thanks for ur reply .but i need 2 first later 5,then only i will be able to get the solution.can you pls help me